# Why can't I redirect to an page with spring security?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

It is too simple.
If I input the url of /toQuestion in the browser, I will redirect to the page I want successfully.
But, by my js code:

```
window.location.href = "/toQuestion";
```

I will back to the login page which I configured:

```
http.authorizeRequests(
                authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .mvcMatchers(
                                "/js/**",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/chief",
                                "/toQuestion").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        )
.formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/chief")
                                .permitAll()
                )
```

Is there any configuration I need to set up?

Answer (score 1):

You can change log level of package org.springframework.security to debug and see the reason of redirecting to login page.

Comment: OK.I solved it.Because I didn't implement the supports method of AuthenticationProvider to indicate which Authentication Object this AuthenticationProvider supports.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're permiting only authenticated users, that's why it's redirecting. For non user authenticated you must do something like:

```
...http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
"/toQuestion").permitAll();...
```

Comment: I have given permission of "/toQuestion" to any unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

OK.I solved it.Because I didn't implement the supports method of AuthenticationProvider to indicate which Authentication Object this AuthenticationProvider supports.